# In Reactjs Getting an error .map() is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, django, api

when i try to fetch response from api i got map is not a function error .but i declared state as array.

Here's the code:

```
function VendorListScreen(){

const [vendorsList,setVendorsList]=useState([]);

const getVendors =()=>{
axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/vendors/').then((res)=>{
    setVendorsList(res.data)
})

}


    <h1>Vendor</h1>
    <button onClick={getVendors}>get</button>
    {vendorsList.map(vendor=>{
        return <p>{vendor.name}</p>
    })}
```

Answer (score 1):

Verify first if your "res.data" from API return is an array. It's also possible that your component gets mounted first before the API request gets resolved.

Answer (score 0):

if `api` response returns an array, call `map` after state is updated with data:

```
 <button onClick={getVendors}>get</button>
    {vendorsList && vendorsList.map(vendor=>{
        return <p>{vendor.name}</p>
    })}
```